# Generate log in VBS, text with spaces and variables

Tags: shell, logging, vbscript

I want to create log files in visual script, containing a text with spaces and adding a variable at the end.
I call Generate.bat which adds date and time to each log line, and then I add a text and then the variable.
On the first option, I get [Date] Var_Number1 (If I add any space, it will end there)
On the second option, and here is my problem, I get [Date] Var Number, with spaces as I want, but I'm not able to add the variable, I have made many tests, but I can't get it.

```
DIM variable
variable = 1

CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "C:\Generatelog.bat", "C:\Sample.log Var_Number" & variable, "", "open", 0

CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "C:\Generatelog.bat", "C:\Sample.log ""Var Number""", "", "open", 0
```

Generate.bat code:

```
set V_HOUR=%time: =0%
set V_DATEHOUR=%date% - %V_HOUR:~0,8%
set V_FILE=%1
set V_TEXT=%~2

echo [%V_DATEHOUR%] - %V_TEXT% >> %V_FILE%
```

Thanks

Comment: For further assistance, can you post your code for `Generatelog.bat` please.

Comment: Did you try `CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "C:\Generatelog.bat", """C:\Sample.log Var Number" & variable & """", "", "open", 0` and `CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "C:\Generatelog.bat", """C:\Sample.log Var Number" & variable & """", "", "open", 0` ?

Comment: This generates a file named "Sample.log Var Number 1""

Comment: I have added Generate.bat code on the first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any non-working code I am unable to explain what you did wrong, but the following should work, assuming that you want the argument to be `"Var Number1"`:

```vbs
CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "C:\Generatelog.bat" _
  , "C:\Sample.log ""Var Number" & variable & """", "", "open", 0
```

However, shelling out is a rather complicated way to do logging and I'd recommend against it. Writing to a log file can be handled perfectly fine from within VBScript like this:

```vbs
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

logfile  = "C:\Sample.log"
variable = 1
message  = "Var Number" & variable

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(logfile, 2, True)
f.WriteLine "[" & Date & " - " & Time & "] " & message
f.Close
```

Since I need stuff like this rather frequently I wrapped my logging routines in a class ([`CLogger`](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/clogger.shtml)) that can easily be included in other scripts. It can be used like this:

```vbs
'import or copy/paste the class code

Set clog = New CLogger
clog.IncludeTimestamp = True
clog.LogFile = "C:\Sample.log"
clog.LogToConsole = False

variable = 1

clog.LogInfo "Var Number" & variable
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect. I use external file to be more dynamic, and I always call Generate.bat from any .vbs and .bat to make a log.